# Working through duplicates along rows in DataFrame and deleting all except the last one in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I am miserably stuck at Pandas Data Cleaning. I have made simple example to demonstrate my problem. For each row, I want to delete the duplicates and keep the last one. Currently, my DataFrame is 'animals'. And I want it to be the DataFrame 'animals_clean'

Imagine this DataFrame. You can see duplicates along axis=0, e.g. 'cat' is repeated in row 0

```
list_of_animals = [['cat','dog','monkey','sparrow', 'cat'],['cow', 'eagle','rat', 'eagle', 'owl'],['deer', 'horse', 'goat', 'falcon', 'falcon']]
animals = pd.DataFrame(list_of_animals)
```

How it looks:

[image: Click here! This is how it looks]

This is the result I want. You can see the duplicates in each row is marked 'X' keeping the last one.

```
list_of_animals_clean = [['X','dog','monkey','sparrow', 'cat'],['cow', 'X','rat', 'eagle', 'owl'], ['deer', 'horse', 'goat', 'X', 'falcon']]
animals_clean = pd.DataFrame(list_of_animals_clean)
```

Should look like:

[image: Click here! This is how it should look like]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas-dataframe-apply) + [mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html#pandas-series-mask) + [duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html#pandas-series-duplicated) with keep='last':

```
import pandas as pd

list_of_animals = [['cat', 'dog', 'monkey', 'sparrow', 'cat'],
                   ['cow', 'eagle', 'rat', 'eagle', 'owl'],
                   ['deer', 'horse', 'goat', 'falcon', 'falcon']]
animals = pd.DataFrame(list_of_animals)

animals = animals.apply(
    lambda s: s.mask(s.duplicated(keep='last'), 'x'),
    axis=1
)

print(animals)
```

Output:

```
      0      1       2        3       4
0     x    dog  monkey  sparrow     cat
1   cow      x     rat    eagle     owl
2  deer  horse    goat        x  falcon
```

Comment: Thank you so much Henry Ecker. Your answer helped my problem a lot :)

Comment: Kindly help me with another confusion. Why did we use axis=1? We had to go through the rows, which is axis=0 right?

Comment: We had to go _across_ rows. We apply to axis 1 so the function is applied to all columns in the row. Rather than all rows in the column (axis=0).